# ASP.NET Core 3 publish single exe also include wwwroot

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

Want to publish ASP.NET Core 3 project to single exe. How can i include/exclude wwwroot(js/css) to exe file?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to publish project exclude some files ,you can add these code in `xxx.csproj`

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="wwwroot/css/*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="wwwroot/js/*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Then `js` and `css` files are excluded.