# VS 2019, exclude wwwroot\js\src folder from publishing to IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and trying to exclude wwwroot\js\src files from getting copied to IIS when publishing. Similar questions have been asked but those what I have referred to don't work because some of the project file syntax shown in those examples are not valid. Even the Microsoft documented method is not working.

[MS Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment) - wpp.target files has no effect on publish. It still copies the wwwroot\js\src files.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613474/asp-net-core-3-publish-single-exe-also-include-wwwroot) - In vs 2019; CopyToPublishDirectory is not a valid attribute to Content tag. However the valid syntax below:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Content Update="wwwroot\js\src\**"> 
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>false</CopyToPublishDirectory>
     </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

still publishes the js\src folder to IIS.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173811/how-do-i-exclude-files-folders-from-a-net-core-standard-project) - doesn't help either.

This must be quite a simple task and yet not straight forward way to get it done. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

This syntax worked after I add it to the csproj file. However the according to intellisense says it's invalid, but it works. Seems to be an issue on Microsoft side

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\js\src\**\*">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

The tooltip says **CopyToPublishDirectory** can only have a boolean value of true/false
and If I do that this doesn't work!